# Selecting appropriate tool for replacement of IBM DataStage ETL tool

Tags: datastage

we are looking for replacement of existing IBM DataStage platform . it has had around 1500 + mappings/datastage jobs on-premise . these mapping have also some complex transformations and mappings. 
It is a complete ETL architecture on-premise. If it needs to get replace (Datastage) with microsoft platform (SSIS or Azure data factory) , what are the options to get replace with SSIS ETL tool .

Option:

1. if SSIS ETL tool selected , it needs to re-write all datastage scrips (with etl transformation) to SSIS 
   and then SSIS packege can be run through Azure Data factory.  this will also incur new license cost for SSIS.
2. Can we re-write all ETL datastage jobs/scripts in Azure Data factory , would it be recommended as 
   Azure Data factory is orchestration tool and mainly used for Data driven movement. Azure data factory is not a traditional ETL tool

if anyone can through some lights on DataStage ETL architecture and its rich in build transformation.

and advised which would best option for datastage replacement.
Regards,
mangesh
mangesh7632@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you're looking for a DataStage replacement. If you're still interested, come take a look at what we're building in our new DataStage SaaS product. Here, you'll get a true subscription pay-as-you-go model (if pricing was the issue)

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/getting-started-using-the-new-ibm-datastage-saas-beta-service/

Happy to chat with you. Let me know if you'd like me to email you.

Best wishes with your data integration endeavors.

**Kevin Wei - Product Manager, IBM**